# Unity Desktop not Clickable

Tags: drivers, unity, graphics, suspend, amd-graphics

Hi I have some Problems with my Unity Desktop, I can't click on any window.  I have to go to tty0 <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and back to my XSession with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> then it works fine. Why is this happen? And is there a solution for this?

The other problem is when I wake up by Ubuntu from suspend mode, the desktop is absolutely frozen.

Maybe there some problems with my graphic card ?

`lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2`

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] [1002:67df] (rev cf)
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Radeon RX 470/480 [174b:e347]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

Please help. Thanks.